# Pandas concat columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df-s:

[image]

I want to concatenate along the columns, e.g. get a 1000x61118 DataFrame. so I'm doing:

```
df_full = pd.concat([df_dev, df_temp2], axis=1)
df_full
```

This, however, yields a 2000x61118 df, and fills everything with NaNs... And I have no idea why. What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: may be the index of the 2 columns are not aligned. try with `pd.concat([df_dev.reset_index(drop=True), df_temp2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create default index values by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for correct align both `DataFrame`s:

```
df_full = pd.concat([df_dev.reset_index(drop=True), df_temp2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```